# Why while loop in function only return 1 row data?

Tags: php

I'm doing a function(), and I want to show all the data when I call the function in the foreach loop.

Suddenly while the function is not working, it only returns the first row of data, but in the database has 2 rows of data.

**Below is my code:**

```
function getComments($conn,$postId){

    $commentSql = "    SELECT comments.id, comments.user_id, comments.user_desc, comments.timestamp, user.firstname, user.lastname 
                       FROM comments 
                       INNER JOIN user 
                       ON user.id = comments.user_id
                       WHERE post_id = ? ";

    if($commentStmt = $conn->prepare($commentSql)){
        $commentStmt->bind_param("i", $postId);
        $commentStmt->execute();

        $commentStmt->bind_result($commentId, $userId, $userComment, $comment_timestamp, $user_firstname, $user_lastname);

        while ($commentStmt->fetch()) {
            echo "user dec: $userComment comment id: $commentId";

        }
        $commentStmt->close();
    }else{
        return "error preparing sql";
    }
}
```

**When I call function in for each loop:**

```
echo getComments($conn,$post_id);
```

**Table comments:**

[image]

**My Current output showing 1-row data only:**

[image]

Comment: But both have different `post_id`. And may be you are trying yto  pass `6` as `$post_id` that why only one record is diplayed

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`WHERE post_id = ? ";`

you are passing a post id which is different in two comments. One is with id 6 another is with 9.

Comment: Thank you, that a miss take, now I can get all rows data.

Comment: This is not a answer. This should be written as comment.